# Minecraft Java Minecraft.getMinecraft cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, minecraft

I recently started coding a mod for Minecraft and I can't get past this one stupid error. "`Minecraft.getMinecraft` cannot be resolved to a type". I don't know how to fix this, I was watching a tutorial and I had the same version and everything.

I checked all the code, and everything is right. If someone could help that would be much appreciated since I really don't want to give up and I really want to finish this mod. Thanks!

The module code where I get the error:

```java
package module;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class Module {

    public Minecraft mc = new Minecraft.getMinecraft();

    private String name, displayName;
    private int key;
    private Category category;
    private boolean toggled;

}
```

Comment: take off that "new"

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to flag your answer as "answer" but still thanks alot!

Comment: glad you did it : ) No probs mate, don't mind about reputation, it was just a lil mistake.

Comment: @Frasski, you can mark any answer you like from below as accepted by clicking a check mark, then we'll know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call the constructor of `Minecraft` it should look like:

```
public Minecraft mc = new Minecraft(...);
```

If you don't want to call constructor but use some static method of the class `Minecraft` called `getMinecraft()` you should remove the "new" keyword [like Asier Aranbarri said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591025/minecraft-java-minecraft-getminecraft-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/54591229#comment95978379_54591025) like this:

```
public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
```

Answer (score 1):

The code examples on [Java Code Examples for net.minecraft.client.Minecraft](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=net.minecraft.client.Minecraft) agree with [the comment by Asier Arranbari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591025/minecraft-java-minecraft-getminecraft-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/54591284?noredirect=1#comment95978379_54591025): It should be

```
    public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
```

That is, without `new`.

**What happened?**

When you did `new Minecraft.getMinecraft()`, the compiler assumed that `Minecraft.getMinecraft` was a class that you tried to instantiate by invoking a no-arg constructor. That is, a class named `getMinecraft` inside the `Minecraft` class. However, `getMinecraft` is a (static) method, not a class. Therefore you got the message “Minecraft.getMinecraft cannot be resolved to a type”.

Comment: Does this add anything new to the existing set of answers?

Comment: @InfectedDrake It was posted before the one by PeaBrain. Compared to the existing one by Dennis van Opstal it added the correct choice between the two options he gave (with source reference).

Comment: Idk, your answers says it was answered 43 mins ago while PeaBrains one is 41 mins ago, i.e. 2 mins ago before your answered. :)

Comment: It seems there’s some latency somewhere in the system. In my browser they are both at 44 min. The blue box “1 new answer to this question” announcing the other answer only turned up here after I had posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
 public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
```

`getMinecraft()` is a static method of the `Minecraft` class, so it is called using `Minecraft.getMinecraft()`. The `new` keyword is only needed when instantiating a new Object, which is not the case here.